# Get the <a> element in the Site.Master in another content page?

Tags: c#, html, webforms

I have an HTML element `<a>` in my Site.Master in my webforms. I designed it like this:

```
<li>
    <a  runat="server" id="sbHome" href="Dashboard.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
        <span class="micon bi bi-house"></span><span class="mtext">Home</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

I am trying to get the `sbHome` in my Dashboard to set it active on my code behind, like this.

```
 HtmlGenericControl aControl = Master.FindControl("sbHome") as HtmlGenericControl;
 if (aControl != null)
 {
    aControl.Attributes.Clear();
    aControl.Attributes.Add("class", "dropdown-toggle no-arrow active");             
 }
```

yet, The `Master.FindControl` method returns null. How can I possibly get this element
from my content page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Hyperlink control instead of `<a>`, since asp.NET provided a control to replace `<a>` and is easier to manage or modify in codebehind, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the HTML tags doesn't allow to reach the elements inside of it, and the `<li>` is probably one of them
Try using the C# inside of the asp page.

```
<li><% if (yourCondition == something)
{ %>
    <a href="#" runat="server" ID="blabla" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow" />

<% } else{ %>
    <a href="#" runat="server" ID="blabla" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow active"/>
<% } %>
```

You can use C# inside of the asp by putting the code block in this format `<% your C# code %>`

Hope this help you.